# MySQL: Identifying movie run time from text field

Tags: mysql, marc

I have a MySQL text field in xml format that can be queried as follows:

```
ExtractValue(m.metadata,'//datafield[@tag=300]/subfield[@code="a"]') AS multi_disc
```

It produces strings like the following:

```
5 videodiscs (1060 min.)
4 videodiscs (14 hr., 25 min.)
5 videodiscs (approximately 596 min.)
3 videodiscs (729 min.) :
```

I'd like to come up with a way to isolate DVD sets with 5 hour run times or greater. I can think of a way for the listings with minutes only, but not sure how to filter the ones with hours as well.

UPDATE: I have decided to download this as a CSV and do some post-processing with `perl`. Still open to any pure SQL solutions.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL? And what application language are you using?

Comment: @Nick I'm looking for a MySQL query formulation for isolating and comparing a substring to a number. This is a MySQL database.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Server version: 5.5.41-0